# How is <button> read in JavaScript without using querySelector or getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a JavaScript file that contains has an onclick method attached to an element in the HTML, but I never selected it in the JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function() {
    createSketchpad(0);
};

function createSketchpad(size) {
    const sketchpad = document.querySelector('.sketchpad');
    sketchpad.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    sketchpad.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    for(var i = 0; i < Math.pow(size,2); i ++) {
        var gridIndex = document.createElement('div');
        gridIndex.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        sketchpad.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', gridIndex);
    }
};

submitSizeButton.onclick = function chooseSketchpadSize() {
    var submitSizeInput  = document.querySelector('.submitSizeInput').value;
    createSketchpad(submitSizeInput);
};
```

HTML body

```
    <body>
        <div class="sketchpad">   
        </div>
        <input class="submitSizeInput"type="text"> 
      <button id="submitSizeButton" name="clickme" type="submit"> </button>


    <script src="index.js"> </script>
      
</body>
```

As seen above, submitSizeButton was never defined in the JavaScript, but in my HTML I have a button with an ID set to submitSizeButton. My question is, how come I do not have to use *document.querySelector* or *document.getElementById* to bring it to the DOM?

However, if this does not work with other elements such as the input class. How come that does not become a global attribute as well the same as the id does for the button?

Here is a full CodePen: https://codepen.io/fwan0/pen/GRymErp